# C++ shared_ptr<vector> mechanism

Tags: c++

I'm so unsure that I am deallocating memory right. I am probably unable to figure out is shared_ptr destroyed or not, it seems to be impossible according to if checks, so maybe I need some try catch. I would like to listen ideas and ways of improving this code. Thanks. However, I'm so unsure that it prints that vector is empty, it might be destroyed though. Maybe there's something better solution according to C++23.

````
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>
void fillvec(std::vector<int> &vec)
{
    if (!vec.empty())
    {
        unsigned index = 0;
        for (auto &item: vec)
        {
            std::cout << "Enter [" << ++index << "] vector's element : " << std::endl;
            std::cin >> item;
        }
    }
    else
        std::cout << "Impossible to fill vector." << std::endl;
}
void printvec(const std::vector<int> &vec)
{
    if (!vec.empty())
    {
        for (const auto &item : vec)
        {
            std::cout << item << "\t";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
    else
        std::cout << "Impossible to print empty vector!" << std::endl;
}
void clearvec(std::vector<int> &vec)
{
    if (!vec.empty())
    {
        vec.clear();
        std::cout << "Vector has been cleared!" << std::endl;
    }
    else
        std::cout << "Vector is already empty!" << std::endl;
}

void inputsize(int &size)
{
    while (size > 10 || size < 1)
    {
        std::cout << "Enter vector's size : " << std::endl;
        std::cin >> size;
        if (size > 10 || size < 1)
            std::cout << "Enter vector's size from 1 to 10." << std::endl;
    }
}
void destroysp(std::shared_ptr<std::vector<int>> &vec)
{
    vec.~shared_ptr();
    std::cout << "Shared pointer to vector has been destroyed." << std::endl;
}
int main()
{
    int n = 0;
    inputsize(n);
    std::shared_ptr<std::vector<int>> vec = std::make_shared<std::vector<int>>(n);
    fillvec(*vec);
    printvec(*vec);
    destroysp(vec);
    clearvec(*vec);
    printvec(*vec);
}
```
````

Comment: Did you run your code under Valgrind or similar, to check that allocation and reclamation match up?  That seems a good thing to do when you're uncertain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>Your code should work as expected.

I don't see any big issues with memory management.</strike>

It is not very normal to manual call the destructor:

```
   vec.~shared_ptr();
```

This is an exceedingly advanced thing to do and the situations where you would do it are very limited (and I would not expect anybody to do that).

Remove this line.
The vector will be destoryed by the `shared_ptr` destructor. The shared_ptr destructor will be called when execution finishes the main() function (because vec is an automatic variable in the scope of the function main).

You could replace it with

```
vec.reset(); // this will destory the container pointer.
             // but also sets the pointer to nullptr.
             // as a result you can not use `*vec` after a call to 
             // destroysp()
```

**BUT** it looks like you are learning C++ from a Java book. I know that in Java you need to create all objects with `new` but in C++ you can just declare local variable, they are created locally in the local scope and are automatically destroyed when they go out of scope.

Hence: The thing I would change is:

```
std::shared_ptr<std::vector<int>> vec = std::make_shared<std::vector<int>>(n);
```

Into:

```
std::vector<int> vec(n);
```

Then in the rest of main you remove the `*` from infornt of `vec`.

Comment: Sadly, that's a homework, I have to use "new", because of that.

Comment: I'm surprised you think it works as expected, @Martin - Valgrind tells me very different.

Comment: @TobySpeight Opps. Did I miss `vec.~shared_ptr();`

Comment: I'm writing an answer now that addresses that.

Answer (score 1):

`inputsize` has some problems.  Firstly, it really ought to return the value (and I'd expect that value to be a `std::size_t`, rather than `int`, given the name), rather than writing through a reference.

Secondly, it never checks whether the `>>` operation was successful.  When I ran the program with a disconnected stdin, it looped infinitely - same when I provided a non-numeric string as input.

Robust input reading is quite a hard problem - you'll probably find good questions here addressing that.  I'm tempted to write one myself and ask for reviews, just to show how hard it can be.

---

The thing that immediately jumps out as odd is the explicit call to destructor here:

```
void destroysp(std::shared_ptr<std::vector<int>> &vec)
{
    vec.~shared_ptr();
}
```

That's something you usually only do if you're using placement-`new` and managing the raw memory yourself.

I think that's what leads to these Valgrind errors:

```
valgrind --leak-check=full ./275959 <<<'2 3 5'
==692192== Invalid read of size 8
==692192==    at 0x109AB4: __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int const*, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >::__normal_iterator(int const* const&) (stl_iterator.h:1011)
==692192==    by 0x109996: std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >::end() const (stl_vector.h:839)
==692192==    by 0x1098D3: std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >::empty() const (stl_vector.h:1008)
==692192==    by 0x109453: clearvec(std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >&) (275959.cpp:33)
==692192==    by 0x109631: main (275959.cpp:65)
==692192==  Address 0x4de7118 is 24 bytes inside a block of size 40 free'd
==692192==    at 0x484299B: operator delete(void*, unsigned long) (in /usr/libexec/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==692192==    by 0x10A69D: __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2> >::deallocate(std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>*, unsigned long) (new_allocator.h:145)
==692192==    by 0x10A38F: deallocate (allocator.h:199)
==692192==    by 0x10A38F: std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2> > >::deallocate(std::allocator<std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2> >&, std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>*, unsigned long) (alloc_traits.h:496)
==692192==    by 0x10A10B: std::__allocated_ptr<std::allocator<std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2> > >::~__allocated_ptr() (allocated_ptr.h:74)
==692192==    by 0x10AE22: std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::_M_destroy() (shared_ptr_base.h:538)
==692192==    by 0x109C51: std::_Sp_counted_base<(__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::_M_release() (shared_ptr_base.h:184)
==692192==    by 0x1099EA: std::__shared_count<(__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::~__shared_count() (shared_ptr_base.h:705)
==692192==    by 0x10989B: std::__shared_ptr<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::~__shared_ptr() (shared_ptr_base.h:1154)
==692192==    by 0x1098B7: std::shared_ptr<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >::~shared_ptr() (shared_ptr.h:122)
==692192==    by 0x10958C: destroysp(std::shared_ptr<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >&) (275959.cpp:54)
==692192==    by 0x10961D: main (275959.cpp:64)
==692192==  Block was alloc'd at
==692192==    at 0x483FF2F: operator new(unsigned long) (in /usr/libexec/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==692192==    by 0x10A661: __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2> >::allocate(unsigned long, void const*) (new_allocator.h:127)
==692192==    by 0x10A2FB: allocate (allocator.h:185)
==692192==    by 0x10A2FB: std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2> > >::allocate(std::allocator<std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2> >&, unsigned long) (alloc_traits.h:464)
==692192==    by 0x10A0B7: std::__allocated_ptr<std::allocator<std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2> > > std::__allocate_guarded<std::allocator<std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2> > >(std::allocator<std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2> >&) (allocated_ptr.h:98)
==692192==    by 0x109F44: std::__shared_count<(__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::__shared_count<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, int&>(std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >*&, std::_Sp_alloc_shared_tag<std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > > >, int&) (shared_ptr_base.h:648)
==692192==    by 0x109E79: std::__shared_ptr<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::__shared_ptr<std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, int&>(std::_Sp_alloc_shared_tag<std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > > >, int&) (shared_ptr_base.h:1342)
==692192==    by 0x109D8A: std::shared_ptr<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >::shared_ptr<std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, int&>(std::_Sp_alloc_shared_tag<std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > > >, int&) (shared_ptr.h:409)
==692192==    by 0x109CC0: std::shared_ptr<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > > std::allocate_shared<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, int&>(std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > > const&, int&) (shared_ptr.h:863)
==692192==    by 0x109A2F: std::shared_ptr<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > > std::make_shared<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, int&>(int&) (shared_ptr.h:879)
==692192==    by 0x1095E9: main (275959.cpp:61)
==692192== 
==692192== Invalid read of size 8
==692192==    at 0x109AB4: __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int const*, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >::__normal_iterator(int const* const&) (stl_iterator.h:1011)
==692192==    by 0x10996C: std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >::begin() const (stl_vector.h:821)
==692192==    by 0x1098E3: std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >::empty() const (stl_vector.h:1008)
==692192==    by 0x109453: clearvec(std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >&) (275959.cpp:33)
==692192==    by 0x109631: main (275959.cpp:65)
==692192==  Address 0x4de7110 is 16 bytes inside a block of size 40 free'd
==692192==    at 0x484299B: operator delete(void*, unsigned long) (in /usr/libexec/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==692192==    by 0x10A69D: __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2> >::deallocate(std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>*, unsigned long) (new_allocator.h:145)
==692192==    by 0x10A38F: deallocate (allocator.h:199)
==692192==    by 0x10A38F: std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2> > >::deallocate(std::allocator<std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2> >&, std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>*, unsigned long) (alloc_traits.h:496)
==692192==    by 0x10A10B: std::__allocated_ptr<std::allocator<std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2> > >::~__allocated_ptr() (allocated_ptr.h:74)
==692192==    by 0x10AE22: std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::_M_destroy() (shared_ptr_base.h:538)
==692192==    by 0x109C51: std::_Sp_counted_base<(__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::_M_release() (shared_ptr_base.h:184)
==692192==    by 0x1099EA: std::__shared_count<(__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::~__shared_count() (shared_ptr_base.h:705)
==692192==    by 0x10989B: std::__shared_ptr<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::~__shared_ptr() (shared_ptr_base.h:1154)
==692192==    by 0x1098B7: std::shared_ptr<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >::~shared_ptr() (shared_ptr.h:122)
==692192==    by 0x10958C: destroysp(std::shared_ptr<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >&) (275959.cpp:54)
==692192==    by 0x10961D: main (275959.cpp:64)
==692192==  Block was alloc'd at
==692192==    at 0x483FF2F: operator new(unsigned long) (in /usr/libexec/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==692192==    by 0x10A661: __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2> >::allocate(unsigned long, void const*) (new_allocator.h:127)
==692192==    by 0x10A2FB: allocate (allocator.h:185)
==692192==    by 0x10A2FB: std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2> > >::allocate(std::allocator<std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2> >&, unsigned long) (alloc_traits.h:464)
==692192==    by 0x10A0B7: std::__allocated_ptr<std::allocator<std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2> > > std::__allocate_guarded<std::allocator<std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2> > >(std::allocator<std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2> >&) (allocated_ptr.h:98)
==692192==    by 0x109F44: std::__shared_count<(__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::__shared_count<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, int&>(std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >*&, std::_Sp_alloc_shared_tag<std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > > >, int&) (shared_ptr_base.h:648)
==692192==    by 0x109E79: std::__shared_ptr<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::__shared_ptr<std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, int&>(std::_Sp_alloc_shared_tag<std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > > >, int&) (shared_ptr_base.h:1342)
==692192==    by 0x109D8A: std::shared_ptr<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >::shared_ptr<std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, int&>(std::_Sp_alloc_shared_tag<std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > > >, int&) (shared_ptr.h:409)
==692192==    by 0x109CC0: std::shared_ptr<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > > std::allocate_shared<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, int&>(std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > > const&, int&) (shared_ptr.h:863)
==692192==    by 0x109A2F: std::shared_ptr<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > > std::make_shared<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, int&>(int&) (shared_ptr.h:879)
==692192==    by 0x1095E9: main (275959.cpp:61)
==692192== 
==692192== Invalid read of size 8
==692192==    at 0x1099AE: std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >::clear() (stl_vector.h:1499)
==692192==    by 0x109466: clearvec(std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >&) (275959.cpp:35)
==692192==    by 0x109631: main (275959.cpp:65)
==692192==  Address 0x4de7110 is 16 bytes inside a block of size 40 free'd
==692192==    at 0x484299B: operator delete(void*, unsigned long) (in /usr/libexec/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==692192==    by 0x10A69D: __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2> >::deallocate(std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>*, unsigned long) (new_allocator.h:145)
==692192==    by 0x10A38F: deallocate (allocator.h:199)
==692192==    by 0x10A38F: std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2> > >::deallocate(std::allocator<std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2> >&, std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>*, unsigned long) (alloc_traits.h:496)
==692192==    by 0x10A10B: std::__allocated_ptr<std::allocator<std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2> > >::~__allocated_ptr() (allocated_ptr.h:74)
==692192==    by 0x10AE22: std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::_M_destroy() (shared_ptr_base.h:538)
==692192==    by 0x109C51: std::_Sp_counted_base<(__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::_M_release() (shared_ptr_base.h:184)
==692192==    by 0x1099EA: std::__shared_count<(__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::~__shared_count() (shared_ptr_base.h:705)
==692192==    by 0x10989B: std::__shared_ptr<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::~__shared_ptr() (shared_ptr_base.h:1154)
==692192==    by 0x1098B7: std::shared_ptr<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >::~shared_ptr() (shared_ptr.h:122)
==692192==    by 0x10958C: destroysp(std::shared_ptr<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >&) (275959.cpp:54)
==692192==    by 0x10961D: main (275959.cpp:64)
==692192==  Block was alloc'd at
==692192==    at 0x483FF2F: operator new(unsigned long) (in /usr/libexec/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==692192==    by 0x10A661: __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2> >::allocate(unsigned long, void const*) (new_allocator.h:127)
==692192==    by 0x10A2FB: allocate (allocator.h:185)
==692192==    by 0x10A2FB: std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2> > >::allocate(std::allocator<std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2> >&, unsigned long) (alloc_traits.h:464)
==692192==    by 0x10A0B7: std::__allocated_ptr<std::allocator<std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2> > > std::__allocate_guarded<std::allocator<std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2> > >(std::allocator<std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2> >&) (allocated_ptr.h:98)
==692192==    by 0x109F44: std::__shared_count<(__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::__shared_count<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, int&>(std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >*&, std::_Sp_alloc_shared_tag<std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > > >, int&) (shared_ptr_base.h:648)
==692192==    by 0x109E79: std::__shared_ptr<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::__shared_ptr<std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, int&>(std::_Sp_alloc_shared_tag<std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > > >, int&) (shared_ptr_base.h:1342)
==692192==    by 0x109D8A: std::shared_ptr<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >::shared_ptr<std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, int&>(std::_Sp_alloc_shared_tag<std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > > >, int&) (shared_ptr.h:409)
==692192==    by 0x109CC0: std::shared_ptr<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > > std::allocate_shared<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, int&>(std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > > const&, int&) (shared_ptr.h:863)
==692192==    by 0x109A2F: std::shared_ptr<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > > std::make_shared<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, int&>(int&) (shared_ptr.h:879)
==692192==    by 0x1095E9: main (275959.cpp:61)
==692192== 
==692192== Invalid read of size 8
==692192==    at 0x109AD6: std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >::_M_erase_at_end(int*) (stl_vector.h:1794)
==692192==    by 0x1099BF: std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >::clear() (stl_vector.h:1499)
==692192==    by 0x109466: clearvec(std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >&) (275959.cpp:35)
==692192==    by 0x109631: main (275959.cpp:65)
==692192==  Address 0x4de7118 is 24 bytes inside a block of size 40 free'd
==692192==    at 0x484299B: operator delete(void*, unsigned long) (in /usr/libexec/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==692192==    by 0x10A69D: __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2> >::deallocate(std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>*, unsigned long) (new_allocator.h:145)
==692192==    by 0x10A38F: deallocate (allocator.h:199)
==692192==    by 0x10A38F: std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2> > >::deallocate(std::allocator<std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2> >&, std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>*, unsigned long) (alloc_traits.h:496)
==692192==    by 0x10A10B: std::__allocated_ptr<std::allocator<std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2> > >::~__allocated_ptr() (allocated_ptr.h:74)
==692192==    by 0x10AE22: std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::_M_destroy() (shared_ptr_base.h:538)
==692192==    by 0x109C51: std::_Sp_counted_base<(__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::_M_release() (shared_ptr_base.h:184)
==692192==    by 0x1099EA: std::__shared_count<(__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::~__shared_count() (shared_ptr_base.h:705)
==692192==    by 0x10989B: std::__shared_ptr<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::~__shared_ptr() (shared_ptr_base.h:1154)
==692192==    by 0x1098B7: std::shared_ptr<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >::~shared_ptr() (shared_ptr.h:122)
==692192==    by 0x10958C: destroysp(std::shared_ptr<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >&) (275959.cpp:54)
==692192==    by 0x10961D: main (275959.cpp:64)
==692192==  Block was alloc'd at
==692192==    at 0x483FF2F: operator new(unsigned long) (in /usr/libexec/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==692192==    by 0x10A661: __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2> >::allocate(unsigned long, void const*) (new_allocator.h:127)
==692192==    by 0x10A2FB: allocate (allocator.h:185)
==692192==    by 0x10A2FB: std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2> > >::allocate(std::allocator<std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2> >&, unsigned long) (alloc_traits.h:464)
==692192==    by 0x10A0B7: std::__allocated_ptr<std::allocator<std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2> > > std::__allocate_guarded<std::allocator<std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2> > >(std::allocator<std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2> >&) (allocated_ptr.h:98)
==692192==    by 0x109F44: std::__shared_count<(__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::__shared_count<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, int&>(std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >*&, std::_Sp_alloc_shared_tag<std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > > >, int&) (shared_ptr_base.h:648)
==692192==    by 0x109E79: std::__shared_ptr<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::__shared_ptr<std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, int&>(std::_Sp_alloc_shared_tag<std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > > >, int&) (shared_ptr_base.h:1342)
==692192==    by 0x109D8A: std::shared_ptr<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >::shared_ptr<std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, int&>(std::_Sp_alloc_shared_tag<std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > > >, int&) (shared_ptr.h:409)
==692192==    by 0x109CC0: std::shared_ptr<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > > std::allocate_shared<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, int&>(std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > > const&, int&) (shared_ptr.h:863)
==692192==    by 0x109A2F: std::shared_ptr<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > > std::make_shared<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, int&>(int&) (shared_ptr.h:879)
==692192==    by 0x1095E9: main (275959.cpp:61)
==692192== 
==692192== Invalid read of size 8
==692192==    at 0x109B00: std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >::_M_erase_at_end(int*) (stl_vector.h:1796)
==692192==    by 0x1099BF: std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >::clear() (stl_vector.h:1499)
==692192==    by 0x109466: clearvec(std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >&) (275959.cpp:35)
==692192==    by 0x109631: main (275959.cpp:65)
==692192==  Address 0x4de7118 is 24 bytes inside a block of size 40 free'd
==692192==    at 0x484299B: operator delete(void*, unsigned long) (in /usr/libexec/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==692192==    by 0x10A69D: __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2> >::deallocate(std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>*, unsigned long) (new_allocator.h:145)
==692192==    by 0x10A38F: deallocate (allocator.h:199)
==692192==    by 0x10A38F: std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2> > >::deallocate(std::allocator<std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2> >&, std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>*, unsigned long) (alloc_traits.h:496)
==692192==    by 0x10A10B: std::__allocated_ptr<std::allocator<std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2> > >::~__allocated_ptr() (allocated_ptr.h:74)
==692192==    by 0x10AE22: std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::_M_destroy() (shared_ptr_base.h:538)
==692192==    by 0x109C51: std::_Sp_counted_base<(__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::_M_release() (shared_ptr_base.h:184)
==692192==    by 0x1099EA: std::__shared_count<(__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::~__shared_count() (shared_ptr_base.h:705)
==692192==    by 0x10989B: std::__shared_ptr<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::~__shared_ptr() (shared_ptr_base.h:1154)
==692192==    by 0x1098B7: std::shared_ptr<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >::~shared_ptr() (shared_ptr.h:122)
==692192==    by 0x10958C: destroysp(std::shared_ptr<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >&) (275959.cpp:54)
==692192==    by 0x10961D: main (275959.cpp:64)
==692192==  Block was alloc'd at
==692192==    at 0x483FF2F: operator new(unsigned long) (in /usr/libexec/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==692192==    by 0x10A661: __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2> >::allocate(unsigned long, void const*) (new_allocator.h:127)
==692192==    by 0x10A2FB: allocate (allocator.h:185)
==692192==    by 0x10A2FB: std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2> > >::allocate(std::allocator<std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2> >&, unsigned long) (alloc_traits.h:464)
==692192==    by 0x10A0B7: std::__allocated_ptr<std::allocator<std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2> > > std::__allocate_guarded<std::allocator<std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2> > >(std::allocator<std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2> >&) (allocated_ptr.h:98)
==692192==    by 0x109F44: std::__shared_count<(__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::__shared_count<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, int&>(std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >*&, std::_Sp_alloc_shared_tag<std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > > >, int&) (shared_ptr_base.h:648)
==692192==    by 0x109E79: std::__shared_ptr<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::__shared_ptr<std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, int&>(std::_Sp_alloc_shared_tag<std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > > >, int&) (shared_ptr_base.h:1342)
==692192==    by 0x109D8A: std::shared_ptr<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >::shared_ptr<std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, int&>(std::_Sp_alloc_shared_tag<std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > > >, int&) (shared_ptr.h:409)
==692192==    by 0x109CC0: std::shared_ptr<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > > std::allocate_shared<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, int&>(std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > > const&, int&) (shared_ptr.h:863)
==692192==    by 0x109A2F: std::shared_ptr<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > > std::make_shared<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, int&>(int&) (shared_ptr.h:879)
==692192==    by 0x1095E9: main (275959.cpp:61)
==692192== 
==692192== Invalid write of size 8
==692192==    at 0x109B1B: std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >::_M_erase_at_end(int*) (stl_vector.h:1798)
==692192==    by 0x1099BF: std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >::clear() (stl_vector.h:1499)
==692192==    by 0x109466: clearvec(std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >&) (275959.cpp:35)
==692192==    by 0x109631: main (275959.cpp:65)
==692192==  Address 0x4de7118 is 24 bytes inside a block of size 40 free'd
==692192==    at 0x484299B: operator delete(void*, unsigned long) (in /usr/libexec/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==692192==    by 0x10A69D: __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2> >::deallocate(std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>*, unsigned long) (new_allocator.h:145)
==692192==    by 0x10A38F: deallocate (allocator.h:199)
==692192==    by 0x10A38F: std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2> > >::deallocate(std::allocator<std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2> >&, std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>*, unsigned long) (alloc_traits.h:496)
==692192==    by 0x10A10B: std::__allocated_ptr<std::allocator<std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2> > >::~__allocated_ptr() (allocated_ptr.h:74)
==692192==    by 0x10AE22: std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::_M_destroy() (shared_ptr_base.h:538)
==692192==    by 0x109C51: std::_Sp_counted_base<(__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::_M_release() (shared_ptr_base.h:184)
==692192==    by 0x1099EA: std::__shared_count<(__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::~__shared_count() (shared_ptr_base.h:705)
==692192==    by 0x10989B: std::__shared_ptr<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::~__shared_ptr() (shared_ptr_base.h:1154)
==692192==    by 0x1098B7: std::shared_ptr<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >::~shared_ptr() (shared_ptr.h:122)
==692192==    by 0x10958C: destroysp(std::shared_ptr<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >&) (275959.cpp:54)
==692192==    by 0x10961D: main (275959.cpp:64)
==692192==  Block was alloc'd at
==692192==    at 0x483FF2F: operator new(unsigned long) (in /usr/libexec/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==692192==    by 0x10A661: __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2> >::allocate(unsigned long, void const*) (new_allocator.h:127)
==692192==    by 0x10A2FB: allocate (allocator.h:185)
==692192==    by 0x10A2FB: std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2> > >::allocate(std::allocator<std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2> >&, unsigned long) (alloc_traits.h:464)
==692192==    by 0x10A0B7: std::__allocated_ptr<std::allocator<std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2> > > std::__allocate_guarded<std::allocator<std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2> > >(std::allocator<std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2> >&) (allocated_ptr.h:98)
==692192==    by 0x109F44: std::__shared_count<(__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::__shared_count<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, int&>(std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >*&, std::_Sp_alloc_shared_tag<std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > > >, int&) (shared_ptr_base.h:648)
==692192==    by 0x109E79: std::__shared_ptr<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::__shared_ptr<std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, int&>(std::_Sp_alloc_shared_tag<std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > > >, int&) (shared_ptr_base.h:1342)
==692192==    by 0x109D8A: std::shared_ptr<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >::shared_ptr<std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, int&>(std::_Sp_alloc_shared_tag<std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > > >, int&) (shared_ptr.h:409)
==692192==    by 0x109CC0: std::shared_ptr<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > > std::allocate_shared<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, int&>(std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > > const&, int&) (shared_ptr.h:863)
==692192==    by 0x109A2F: std::shared_ptr<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > > std::make_shared<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, int&>(int&) (shared_ptr.h:879)
==692192==    by 0x1095E9: main (275959.cpp:61)
==692192== 
Vector has been cleared!
==692192== Invalid read of size 8
==692192==    at 0x109AB4: __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int const*, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >::__normal_iterator(int const* const&) (stl_iterator.h:1011)
==692192==    by 0x109996: std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >::end() const (stl_vector.h:839)
==692192==    by 0x1098D3: std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >::empty() const (stl_vector.h:1008)
==692192==    by 0x10935B: printvec(std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > const&) (275959.cpp:20)
==692192==    by 0x109645: main (275959.cpp:66)
==692192==  Address 0x4de7118 is 24 bytes inside a block of size 40 free'd
==692192==    at 0x484299B: operator delete(void*, unsigned long) (in /usr/libexec/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==692192==    by 0x10A69D: __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2> >::deallocate(std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>*, unsigned long) (new_allocator.h:145)
==692192==    by 0x10A38F: deallocate (allocator.h:199)
==692192==    by 0x10A38F: std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2> > >::deallocate(std::allocator<std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2> >&, std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>*, unsigned long) (alloc_traits.h:496)
==692192==    by 0x10A10B: std::__allocated_ptr<std::allocator<std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2> > >::~__allocated_ptr() (allocated_ptr.h:74)
==692192==    by 0x10AE22: std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::_M_destroy() (shared_ptr_base.h:538)
==692192==    by 0x109C51: std::_Sp_counted_base<(__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::_M_release() (shared_ptr_base.h:184)
==692192==    by 0x1099EA: std::__shared_count<(__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::~__shared_count() (shared_ptr_base.h:705)
==692192==    by 0x10989B: std::__shared_ptr<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::~__shared_ptr() (shared_ptr_base.h:1154)
==692192==    by 0x1098B7: std::shared_ptr<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >::~shared_ptr() (shared_ptr.h:122)
==692192==    by 0x10958C: destroysp(std::shared_ptr<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >&) (275959.cpp:54)
==692192==    by 0x10961D: main (275959.cpp:64)
==692192==  Block was alloc'd at
==692192==    at 0x483FF2F: operator new(unsigned long) (in /usr/libexec/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==692192==    by 0x10A661: __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2> >::allocate(unsigned long, void const*) (new_allocator.h:127)
==692192==    by 0x10A2FB: allocate (allocator.h:185)
==692192==    by 0x10A2FB: std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2> > >::allocate(std::allocator<std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2> >&, unsigned long) (alloc_traits.h:464)
==692192==    by 0x10A0B7: std::__allocated_ptr<std::allocator<std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2> > > std::__allocate_guarded<std::allocator<std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2> > >(std::allocator<std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2> >&) (allocated_ptr.h:98)
==692192==    by 0x109F44: std::__shared_count<(__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::__shared_count<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, int&>(std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >*&, std::_Sp_alloc_shared_tag<std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > > >, int&) (shared_ptr_base.h:648)
==692192==    by 0x109E79: std::__shared_ptr<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::__shared_ptr<std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, int&>(std::_Sp_alloc_shared_tag<std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > > >, int&) (shared_ptr_base.h:1342)
==692192==    by 0x109D8A: std::shared_ptr<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >::shared_ptr<std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, int&>(std::_Sp_alloc_shared_tag<std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > > >, int&) (shared_ptr.h:409)
==692192==    by 0x109CC0: std::shared_ptr<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > > std::allocate_shared<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, int&>(std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > > const&, int&) (shared_ptr.h:863)
==692192==    by 0x109A2F: std::shared_ptr<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > > std::make_shared<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, int&>(int&) (shared_ptr.h:879)
==692192==    by 0x1095E9: main (275959.cpp:61)
==692192== 
==692192== Invalid read of size 8
==692192==    at 0x109AB4: __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int const*, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >::__normal_iterator(int const* const&) (stl_iterator.h:1011)
==692192==    by 0x10996C: std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >::begin() const (stl_vector.h:821)
==692192==    by 0x1098E3: std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >::empty() const (stl_vector.h:1008)
==692192==    by 0x10935B: printvec(std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > const&) (275959.cpp:20)
==692192==    by 0x109645: main (275959.cpp:66)
==692192==  Address 0x4de7110 is 16 bytes inside a block of size 40 free'd
==692192==    at 0x484299B: operator delete(void*, unsigned long) (in /usr/libexec/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==692192==    by 0x10A69D: __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2> >::deallocate(std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>*, unsigned long) (new_allocator.h:145)
==692192==    by 0x10A38F: deallocate (allocator.h:199)
==692192==    by 0x10A38F: std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2> > >::deallocate(std::allocator<std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2> >&, std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>*, unsigned long) (alloc_traits.h:496)
==692192==    by 0x10A10B: std::__allocated_ptr<std::allocator<std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2> > >::~__allocated_ptr() (allocated_ptr.h:74)
==692192==    by 0x10AE22: std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::_M_destroy() (shared_ptr_base.h:538)
==692192==    by 0x109C51: std::_Sp_counted_base<(__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::_M_release() (shared_ptr_base.h:184)
==692192==    by 0x1099EA: std::__shared_count<(__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::~__shared_count() (shared_ptr_base.h:705)
==692192==    by 0x10989B: std::__shared_ptr<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::~__shared_ptr() (shared_ptr_base.h:1154)
==692192==    by 0x1098B7: std::shared_ptr<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >::~shared_ptr() (shared_ptr.h:122)
==692192==    by 0x10958C: destroysp(std::shared_ptr<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >&) (275959.cpp:54)
==692192==    by 0x10961D: main (275959.cpp:64)
==692192==  Block was alloc'd at
==692192==    at 0x483FF2F: operator new(unsigned long) (in /usr/libexec/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==692192==    by 0x10A661: __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2> >::allocate(unsigned long, void const*) (new_allocator.h:127)
==692192==    by 0x10A2FB: allocate (allocator.h:185)
==692192==    by 0x10A2FB: std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2> > >::allocate(std::allocator<std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2> >&, unsigned long) (alloc_traits.h:464)
==692192==    by 0x10A0B7: std::__allocated_ptr<std::allocator<std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2> > > std::__allocate_guarded<std::allocator<std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2> > >(std::allocator<std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2> >&) (allocated_ptr.h:98)
==692192==    by 0x109F44: std::__shared_count<(__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::__shared_count<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, int&>(std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >*&, std::_Sp_alloc_shared_tag<std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > > >, int&) (shared_ptr_base.h:648)
==692192==    by 0x109E79: std::__shared_ptr<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::__shared_ptr<std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, int&>(std::_Sp_alloc_shared_tag<std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > > >, int&) (shared_ptr_base.h:1342)
==692192==    by 0x109D8A: std::shared_ptr<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >::shared_ptr<std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, int&>(std::_Sp_alloc_shared_tag<std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > > >, int&) (shared_ptr.h:409)
==692192==    by 0x109CC0: std::shared_ptr<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > > std::allocate_shared<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, int&>(std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > > const&, int&) (shared_ptr.h:863)
==692192==    by 0x109A2F: std::shared_ptr<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > > std::make_shared<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, int&>(int&) (shared_ptr.h:879)
==692192==    by 0x1095E9: main (275959.cpp:61)
==692192== 
Impossible to print empty vector!
==692192== Invalid read of size 4
==692192==    at 0x109B66: __exchange_and_add_single (atomicity.h:84)
==692192==    by 0x109B66: __exchange_and_add_dispatch (atomicity.h:99)
==692192==    by 0x109B66: std::_Sp_counted_base<(__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::_M_release() (shared_ptr_base.h:165)
==692192==    by 0x1099EA: std::__shared_count<(__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::~__shared_count() (shared_ptr_base.h:705)
==692192==    by 0x10989B: std::__shared_ptr<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::~__shared_ptr() (shared_ptr_base.h:1154)
==692192==    by 0x1098B7: std::shared_ptr<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >::~shared_ptr() (shared_ptr.h:122)
==692192==    by 0x109651: main (275959.cpp:67)
==692192==  Address 0x4de7108 is 8 bytes inside a block of size 40 free'd
==692192==    at 0x484299B: operator delete(void*, unsigned long) (in /usr/libexec/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==692192==    by 0x10A69D: __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2> >::deallocate(std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>*, unsigned long) (new_allocator.h:145)
==692192==    by 0x10A38F: deallocate (allocator.h:199)
==692192==    by 0x10A38F: std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2> > >::deallocate(std::allocator<std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2> >&, std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>*, unsigned long) (alloc_traits.h:496)
==692192==    by 0x10A10B: std::__allocated_ptr<std::allocator<std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2> > >::~__allocated_ptr() (allocated_ptr.h:74)
==692192==    by 0x10AE22: std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::_M_destroy() (shared_ptr_base.h:538)
==692192==    by 0x109C51: std::_Sp_counted_base<(__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::_M_release() (shared_ptr_base.h:184)
==692192==    by 0x1099EA: std::__shared_count<(__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::~__shared_count() (shared_ptr_base.h:705)
==692192==    by 0x10989B: std::__shared_ptr<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::~__shared_ptr() (shared_ptr_base.h:1154)
==692192==    by 0x1098B7: std::shared_ptr<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >::~shared_ptr() (shared_ptr.h:122)
==692192==    by 0x10958C: destroysp(std::shared_ptr<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >&) (275959.cpp:54)
==692192==    by 0x10961D: main (275959.cpp:64)
==692192==  Block was alloc'd at
==692192==    at 0x483FF2F: operator new(unsigned long) (in /usr/libexec/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==692192==    by 0x10A661: __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2> >::allocate(unsigned long, void const*) (new_allocator.h:127)
==692192==    by 0x10A2FB: allocate (allocator.h:185)
==692192==    by 0x10A2FB: std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2> > >::allocate(std::allocator<std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2> >&, unsigned long) (alloc_traits.h:464)
==692192==    by 0x10A0B7: std::__allocated_ptr<std::allocator<std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2> > > std::__allocate_guarded<std::allocator<std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2> > >(std::allocator<std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2> >&) (allocated_ptr.h:98)
==692192==    by 0x109F44: std::__shared_count<(__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::__shared_count<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, int&>(std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >*&, std::_Sp_alloc_shared_tag<std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > > >, int&) (shared_ptr_base.h:648)
==692192==    by 0x109E79: std::__shared_ptr<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::__shared_ptr<std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, int&>(std::_Sp_alloc_shared_tag<std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > > >, int&) (shared_ptr_base.h:1342)
==692192==    by 0x109D8A: std::shared_ptr<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >::shared_ptr<std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, int&>(std::_Sp_alloc_shared_tag<std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > > >, int&) (shared_ptr.h:409)
==692192==    by 0x109CC0: std::shared_ptr<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > > std::allocate_shared<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, int&>(std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > > const&, int&) (shared_ptr.h:863)
==692192==    by 0x109A2F: std::shared_ptr<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > > std::make_shared<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, int&>(int&) (shared_ptr.h:879)
==692192==    by 0x1095E9: main (275959.cpp:61)
==692192== 
==692192== Invalid read of size 4
==692192==    at 0x109B6F: __exchange_and_add_single (atomicity.h:85)
==692192==    by 0x109B6F: __exchange_and_add_dispatch (atomicity.h:99)
==692192==    by 0x109B6F: std::_Sp_counted_base<(__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::_M_release() (shared_ptr_base.h:165)
==692192==    by 0x1099EA: std::__shared_count<(__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::~__shared_count() (shared_ptr_base.h:705)
==692192==    by 0x10989B: std::__shared_ptr<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::~__shared_ptr() (shared_ptr_base.h:1154)
==692192==    by 0x1098B7: std::shared_ptr<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >::~shared_ptr() (shared_ptr.h:122)
==692192==    by 0x109651: main (275959.cpp:67)
==692192==  Address 0x4de7108 is 8 bytes inside a block of size 40 free'd
==692192==    at 0x484299B: operator delete(void*, unsigned long) (in /usr/libexec/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==692192==    by 0x10A69D: __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2> >::deallocate(std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>*, unsigned long) (new_allocator.h:145)
==692192==    by 0x10A38F: deallocate (allocator.h:199)
==692192==    by 0x10A38F: std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2> > >::deallocate(std::allocator<std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2> >&, std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>*, unsigned long) (alloc_traits.h:496)
==692192==    by 0x10A10B: std::__allocated_ptr<std::allocator<std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2> > >::~__allocated_ptr() (allocated_ptr.h:74)
==692192==    by 0x10AE22: std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::_M_destroy() (shared_ptr_base.h:538)
==692192==    by 0x109C51: std::_Sp_counted_base<(__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::_M_release() (shared_ptr_base.h:184)
==692192==    by 0x1099EA: std::__shared_count<(__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::~__shared_count() (shared_ptr_base.h:705)
==692192==    by 0x10989B: std::__shared_ptr<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::~__shared_ptr() (shared_ptr_base.h:1154)
==692192==    by 0x1098B7: std::shared_ptr<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >::~shared_ptr() (shared_ptr.h:122)
==692192==    by 0x10958C: destroysp(std::shared_ptr<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >&) (275959.cpp:54)
==692192==    by 0x10961D: main (275959.cpp:64)
==692192==  Block was alloc'd at
==692192==    at 0x483FF2F: operator new(unsigned long) (in /usr/libexec/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==692192==    by 0x10A661: __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2> >::allocate(unsigned long, void const*) (new_allocator.h:127)
==692192==    by 0x10A2FB: allocate (allocator.h:185)
==692192==    by 0x10A2FB: std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2> > >::allocate(std::allocator<std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2> >&, unsigned long) (alloc_traits.h:464)
==692192==    by 0x10A0B7: std::__allocated_ptr<std::allocator<std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2> > > std::__allocate_guarded<std::allocator<std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2> > >(std::allocator<std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2> >&) (allocated_ptr.h:98)
==692192==    by 0x109F44: std::__shared_count<(__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::__shared_count<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, int&>(std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >*&, std::_Sp_alloc_shared_tag<std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > > >, int&) (shared_ptr_base.h:648)
==692192==    by 0x109E79: std::__shared_ptr<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::__shared_ptr<std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, int&>(std::_Sp_alloc_shared_tag<std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > > >, int&) (shared_ptr_base.h:1342)
==692192==    by 0x109D8A: std::shared_ptr<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >::shared_ptr<std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, int&>(std::_Sp_alloc_shared_tag<std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > > >, int&) (shared_ptr.h:409)
==692192==    by 0x109CC0: std::shared_ptr<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > > std::allocate_shared<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, int&>(std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > > const&, int&) (shared_ptr.h:863)
==692192==    by 0x109A2F: std::shared_ptr<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > > std::make_shared<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, int&>(int&) (shared_ptr.h:879)
==692192==    by 0x1095E9: main (275959.cpp:61)
==692192== 
==692192== Invalid write of size 4
==692192==    at 0x109B7A: __exchange_and_add_single (atomicity.h:85)
==692192==    by 0x109B7A: __exchange_and_add_dispatch (atomicity.h:99)
==692192==    by 0x109B7A: std::_Sp_counted_base<(__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::_M_release() (shared_ptr_base.h:165)
==692192==    by 0x1099EA: std::__shared_count<(__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::~__shared_count() (shared_ptr_base.h:705)
==692192==    by 0x10989B: std::__shared_ptr<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::~__shared_ptr() (shared_ptr_base.h:1154)
==692192==    by 0x1098B7: std::shared_ptr<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >::~shared_ptr() (shared_ptr.h:122)
==692192==    by 0x109651: main (275959.cpp:67)
```

(and more)

Comment: That's quite great, but how can I fix destructor? Shall I use "new" somehow before?

Comment: I think you don't want to be calling that destructor directly.   You could just `clear()` the vector.